# creating custom repository fos elastic search

Tags: symfony, elastica, foselasticabundle

im trying to make a simple custom repository in order to understand how elastic search repository works. the documentation is pretty straight forward but i still dont understand how it works, im getting this error  ´The service definition "fos_elastica.manager" does not exist.´. so far i think my problem is in the controller since i dont understand how to intialize them, also i would like to know if im in the right way in my configuration of the custom repository and the simple query i made.

im getting this error with this configuration whenever i try to make a search,

```
 The service definition "fos_elastica.manager" does not exist.
```

this is my configuration so far:
    //app/config.yml

> ```
> fos_elastica:
>     clients:
>         default: { host: localhost, port: 9200 }
>     indexes:
>          sava:
>             client: default
>             types:
>                 blog:
>                     mappings:
>                         id:
>                             type: integer
>                         body : ~
>                         title : ~
>                         tags: ~
>                     persistence:
>                         identifier: id
>                         driver: orm
>                         model: sava\BlogBundle\Entity\TblPost
>                         finder: ~
>                         provider: ~
>                         listener: ~
>                         repository: sava\BlogBundle\SearchRepository\TblPostRepository
> ```

this is my controller action:

```
namespace sava\BlogBundle\Controller;

//custom querys
use FOS\ElasticaBundle\Manager\RepositoryManager;
use FOS\ElasticaBundle\Repository;
//
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

class TblPostController extends Controller
{
        public function getPostAction(Request $request)
    {   
         $container = new ContainerBuilder();
         $repositoryManager = $container->get('fos_elastica.manager');

         $repository = $repositoryManager->getRepository('BlogBundle:TblPost');

        $items2 = $repository->matchExact($categoria,$searchQuery );


         return $this->render('savaBlogBundle:TblPost:index.html.twig', array(
                    'results' => $items2, 'entities' => $items2
        ));
    }
```

this is my post repository:

```
<?php

namespace sava\BlogBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

use FOS\ElasticaBundle\Repository;

class TblPostRepository extends FOS\ElasticaBundle\Repository
{
    public function matchExact($campo, $searchQuery) {


         //$finder = $this->get('fos_elastica.finder.sava.blog');

        $query = new Query();
        if($searchQuery=='')
        {
            $innerQuery = new Query\MatchAll();
        }
        else{
           $innerQuery = new Query\Match();
        $innerQuery->setField( $campo  , array('query' => $searchQuery));
        }
        $query->setQuery($innerQuery);
        $query->setSize(1000000);
        $query->setExplain(true);

        return $this->find($query);
    }  
}
```

and since im using yml this is my tblpost.orm, i did generate my entities.

whenever i do the get postaction it throws me that it cant find the container, and i dont see an example in how to properly intiaze it, also is this is how you make a custom query?

**EDIT 1:**

so i changed this:

```
    $container = new ContainerBuilder();
    $repositoryManager = $container->get('fos_elastica.manager');
```

to this:

```
    $elastica = $this->container->get('fos_elastica.manager');// single entry point, no fancy services    
    $SearchRepository = $elastica->getRepository('savaBlogBundle:TblPostRepository');// single type
```

and im getting this error:

```
 No search finder configured for sava\BlogBundle\Entity\TblPostRepository
```

Answer (score 3):

I've just had the same issue, the soultion is that instead of `savaBlogBundle:TblPostRepository` you should use your entity, for example:

```
$SearchRepository = $elastica->getRepository('savaBlogBundle:TblPost`)
```

Answer (score 0):

According your  fatal error in title of the issue  [enter link description here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle/issues/735)

The main problem why did you get that mistake is that, you assigned the same TblPostRepository in (doctrine config for entity) and in fos_elastica.